# How can we resolve eslint error on <p> tag "Non-interactive elements should not be assigned interactive roles"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Below is the code I am trying to execute, but facing error in converting it to keyboard accessible:

```
<p className={styles['clear-text']} onClick={clearAllFilters}>
  {'Clear All'}
</p
```

Comment: Hey Pulkit. Welome to SO. You have not pasted your code. Please check and edit your question to prevent it from closing

Comment: Thanks tushar for letting me know. i have now editted the code.

Comment: onClick doesn't exist for p tag

Comment: You can add `role="button"` to quiet the eslint error. Synthetic events work for all elements in react.

Answer (score 0):

here is an official explanation https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/no-noninteractive-element-to-interactive-role.md.

In short: either change the element type or make an exception in the eslint settings. Regarding settings, there are 2 options: global setting of special comments